# Testing Promises instead of Callbacks in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS. I'm trying to learn about various concepts including promises. Typically, I'd use callbacks. Now that I'm trying to use promises, I'm trying to figure out how to write tests in this new world. At this time, I have:

```
describe('myModule', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('myModule');
  });

  describe('myService', function () {
    var myService = null;
    beforeEach(inject(function (myService) {
      myService = myService;
    }));

    it('should do my bidding', function () {
      myService.myFunction().then(
        function() { expect(true).toBe(true); },
        function() { expect(false).toBe(false); }
      );
    });
  });
});
```

myService looks like this:

```
myApp.factory('myService', ['$q', function($q) {
    return {
        myFunction: function() {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            defer.resolve();
            return defer.promise;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Essentially, this service always resolves. However, I can't get my test to fail. Even if I change the first `expect` to `false`. I see a log entry that says:

```
log: Spec 'myModule myService should do my bidding' has no expectations.
```

Its like the assertions in the `then` are not executing. What am I misunderstanding?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to test? Seems like you dont have a test.

Comment: Take a look at the async section of the Jasmine docs... http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test asynchronous code, you have to accept a `done` parameter in `it` function, and call it when the test really finished.

And you also have to call `$rootScope.$digest()` to invoke the `then` callbacks.

Therefore, the test should be at least like this:

```
it('should do my bidding', function(done) {
  myService.myFunction().then(
    function() { expect(true).toBe(true); },
    function() { expect(false).toBe(false); }
  ).finally(function() {
    done();
  });

  $rootScope.$digest();
});
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/h68W1IEpAqe6kJwEG6in?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, it took me a lot of trying to understand this logic.